# Error when running a (named) function within a function in R

Tags: r, function

I have a smooth running, but long code (not included here), which I would like to simplify by using multiple functions within a function.

I've tried the following (shortened version). I get an error message (object 'a' not found) if I name the internal function even though I thought that 'a' would be found by the lexical system.

```
DF=data.frame(Loc1 <- c("C","A","A","A","B","C","B"),
          Loc2 <- c("a","a","b","b","a","a","b"),
          Dat1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
          Dat2 <- c(1,2,1,2,1,2,2),
          Dat3 <- c(2,2,4,4,6,5,3))

Inputs <- function(DF, a=NumFac, b=a)
      {
      NumFac <- length(DF[sapply(DF,is.factor)])
      Check()
      p = dim(DF)[2]-a
      Group <- apply(as.data.frame(DF[,1:b]), 1, paste, collapse=".")
      }

Check <- function()
      {
      if(a>=1 && a%%1==0 && b<=a && b>=1 && b%%1==0)
       {}
      else { stop("Incorrect number of factor columns") }
       }

Inputs(DF)
#Error in Check() : object 'a' not found
Inputs(DF,a=1.5)
#Error in Check() : object 'a' not found
```

If I don't name the function but include the whole thing (not really simplifying my code by doing this though...) then I don't get the error, but the code doesn't work as expected.

```
Inputs <- function(DF, a=NumFac, b=a)
      {
      NumFac <- length(DF[sapply(DF,is.factor)])
      function()
       {
        if(a>=1 && a%%1==0 && b<=a && b>=1 && b%%1==0)
        {}
        else { stop("Incorrect number of factor columns") }
       }
      p = dim(DF)[2]-a
      Group <- apply(as.data.frame(DF[,1:b]), 1, paste, collapse=".")
      }

Inputs(DF)
#No error
Inputs(DF,a=1.5)
#No error but no 'stop' either
```

The following works but I don't understand why the earlier two attempts didn't. In the end I would like to include multiple internal functions in the greater 'Inputs' function and I was hoping not to need to provide arguments for all the internal functions (see as they will all be the same!).

```
Inputs <- function(DF, a=NumFac, b=a)
      {
      NumFac <- length(DF[sapply(DF,is.factor)])
      Check(DF, a, b)
      p = dim(DF)[2]-a
      Group <- apply(as.data.frame(DF[,1:b]), 1, paste, collapse=".")
      }

Check <- function(DF, a, b)
      {
      if(a>=1 && a%%1==0 && b<=a && b>=1 && b%%1==0)
       {}
      else { stop("Incorrect number of factor columns") }
       }

Inputs(DF)
#No error
Inputs(DF,a=1.5)
#Error in Check(DF, a, b) :
#  Incorrect number of factor columns
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you signing `a=b` in function declaration, a is only local variable, It's not created in environment, so you can't use it in `Check()`. That's why first attempt don't work.

Comment: It's best practice to pass variables as function arguments. It will save you problems in the long run at the cost of marginally more typing. Also, I wouldn't want to rely on lazy evaluation as you do with `a=NumFac`. It's incredible difficult to find errors later if they depend on that.

Comment: @Adii_ thanks, I didn't realise that. What would be the best solution for this?

Comment: @Roland Thanks. By passing variables as function arguments do you mean to not have empty parenthesis (as in function())? I see this all the time and don't understand when it would be good to use or not. Also, what is a "lazy evaluation" and can you suggest a work around please?

Comment: I mean you should do `fun(a)` if you need `a` inside the function. And lazy evaluation is what let's you do `a = NumFac` when you define `NumFac` inside the function. You could do `a=NULL` and then inside the `Inputs` function `if(is.null(a)) a <- length(...`.

Comment: @Roland Thanks very much especially for the is.null(a) suggestion

Answer (score 0):

About second problem:

```
Inputs <- function(DF, a=NumFac, b=a){
NumFac <- length(DF[sapply(DF,is.factor)])

if(a>=1 && a%%1==0 && b<=a && b>=1 && b%%1==0)
{}
else { stop("Incorrect number of factor columns") }
p = dim(DF)[2]-a
Group <- apply(as.data.frame(DF[,1:b]), 1, paste, collapse=".")
}
```

This will work

Comment: Thanks but this is not really want I'm wanting, as I already have the code to work in this manner. I'm wanting to simplify the code with internal functions (so the code isn't so long). I have been led to believe that this is better practice. My question with this example was (i) why is it not working and (ii) why is it ok with 'a' where the first method was not.

Comment: Responding (i): Function `Check()` try to refer to object `a` that does not exist in global environment. Responding (ii): `Check(a)` is referring to object `a` that not exist in global environment, however you are passing it from function `Input`.